# How to specify a network interface when initialize the Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

I have couple of nodes I need to deploy Kubernetes on them. So they all have couple of NICs. Let's say ens0, ens1, ens2 are the network interfaces and ens0 is the default, but I was requested to use ens1. When I deploy kubernetes it's using the default interface. How do I change it when I initialize the cluster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `--apiserver-advertise-address string` option when initializing kubeadm.

From [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init/): The string is the IP address the API Server will advertise it's listening on. If not set the default network interface will be used.
So something like this should work:

```
kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=10.x.x.x
```

Where 10.x.x.x is the IP associated with your desired interface.